# Ampersand Payment Gateway Error

Tags: magento

We have a huge problem with our magento website (again). This time it is due to the 3rd party plugin called Ampersand Payment Gateway.

During the payment process, after the details are entered, the plugin throws an error:

```
Unlicensed usage of Ampersand's integration suite. Visit ampersandcommerce.com for more information. Message: ampersand_realex_redirect:callback
```

This forbids the gateway to redirect back to our website thus failing to notify us that sale had occurred. I've tried to get hold of Ampersand Commerce guys to no avail.

No changes were ever made to the code - it was working before so no alterations were ever made.

Would somebody have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The clues in the error message... It looks like you need to have a valid licence to use the Ampersand module...

If you have made no changes then it looks like your licence has expired. You will need to keep on at Ampersand to get the new licence.

Good luck.

Comment: Ok, it is hard to get them but I will keep trying. Thank you sulman

Comment: I have worked out using Ampersand Wiki and my backed up files from prior last two months and I found that in the lib catalog of magento I have three license files for Ampersand. I have cross check them and they are identical. That's a big clue, thanks sulman. I'll try to contact Ampersand now.